# LinkedIn Api Login button not showing

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn the login feature onto my site, but the button does not show. The code is:

```
  <head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    <body>

 <script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
</script>
    </body>
</head>
```

I have made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8X9H/136/) it it helps as well.

I'm fairly wet behind the ears in programming so I'm sure its something simple I'm missing when it comes to understanding the api as a whole. A little help would be more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html you've provided is all messed up - body should NOT be above head!. Check [this](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/html/basic-structure-HTML-document.asp) or [this](http://www.basewebmaster.com/html/html5-page-structure.php) out to learn the basics.

[image]

To get the login page follow instructions [linkedin developer page](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin).

First, you need to [get an API key](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api).

Than, build the HTML something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE
  authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInAuth() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .result( function(me) {
      var id = me.values[0].id;
      // AJAX call to pass back id to your server
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a problem of order with your tags. You can't put a body tag in the head. Try perhaps this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
</body>
```

But I'm not sure if your second script is correctly done, as I don't know how the LinkedIn Api works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: YOUR_API_KEY

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="IN/Login">
  Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
</body>
```